# How to detect those functions/constructors only present in source file using LLVM function/module pass?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am writing a module pass from LLVM. In which I need to work on all the functions present in bitcode but at the same time I need to make sure that I am not changing functions which doesn't interest me, i.e. I don't want to consider those functions which are not from source file . How to do that ?

Consider following test file

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int testCall()
{
    return 1;
}

class test
 {
       int a;
     public:
       test()
       {
         a = 0;
       }
       test(int b)
       {
        a = b;
       }
       void foo1()
       {
            a =2;
       }
       void fun()
       {
        a = 3;
       }
 };


int main()
{
    testCall();
     test *a = new test(2);
      test *b = new test(4);
     a->foo1();
     a->fun();

      b->fun();

    cout << "Hi" << "\n";
      return 0;
}
```

I am interested only in finding functions which are defined above, not  other  functions which are detected by LLVM function/module passes as functions. These includes functions having Demangled Names like

1) `std::ios_base::Init::Init()`

2) `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()`

3) `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)`

I don't want to consider these functions while executing my Function/Module pass.
How to do that ?

Comment: But these are present in source. You include them there.

Comment: In clang, you may got *"source file origin"* of token/cursor. I don't know if that info is still present in LLVM bytecode though.

Comment: @Basilevs: yes . I accept that. But  I want to focus on only on code written by developer not on the library functions .

Comment: Filter by namespace?

Comment: @Jarod42  are you referring to sourcemanager class of llvm ?

Comment: @Basilevs i guess that might work . But for that one will  need to keep track of library names present on c++.

Comment: @NimishSakalkale: I didn't use llvm but libclang where the source file info is present. So the info were present before. But, in bytecode and all inlining stuff, not sure if the info is still present.